# Pivot data row to header using SQL in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I get this result using SQL request:

```
NBR_TYPE         Count
-----------------------
0021              20
0022              19
0023              13
```

But i want result like this :

```
0021           0022         0023
---------------------------------
20              19          13
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this using PosgreSQL and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you have a predefined list of values, you can use conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select
    max(count) filter(where nbr_type = '0021') "0021",
    max(count) filter(where nbr_type = '0022') "0022",
    max(count) filter(where nbr_type = '0023') "0023"
from mytable
```

This assumes that each `nbr_type` appears in just one row; otherwise, you possibly want to change the `max()` to a more meaningful aggregation function, such as `sum()` or `avg()`.

Comment: @A.khalifa: nope, this is Postgres syntax. In Oracle, you would do: `max(case when nbr_type = '0021' then count end) "0021"` and so on. As for the title of your question: the term is **pivot** (which I tagged your question with too) rather than *transfer*.